# Error while deploying war file on Tomcat server version 8

Tags: file, tomcat, jenkins, war, deploying

While deploying war file on tomcat server, I am getting below error message:

```
ERROR: Step ‘Deploy war/ear to a container’ aborted due to exception: 
java.lang.InterruptedException: [DeployPublisher][WARN] No wars found. Deploy aborted. %n
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:107)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1878)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Below are my configurations:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kbno.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE7sW.png)

Also,I have restarted tomcat services after giving this roles and users and I am able to access tomcat manually but getting error in jenkins.

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this.